# Showing a set is a root system in a vector space from definition of root system

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Suppose I have the vectors $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with inner products $(\alpha, \alpha) = 1$ and $(\beta, \beta) = 2$, and the angle between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

I want to show $R = \{ \alpha, \beta, -\alpha, -\beta, \alpha + \beta, -\alpha - \beta, 2\alpha + \beta, -2\alpha - \beta \}$ is a root system, that is it satisfies the following:

- $R$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$
- $\forall x \in R$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $rx \in R \iff r = 1$ or $r = -1$
- $\forall x \in R$, $\sigma_x(R) \subset R$
- $\forall x, y \in R$, $<y, x> \in \mathbb{Z}$

With $<y, x> = 2\frac{(y, x)}{(x, x)}$ and $\sigma_x(y) = y - <y, x>x$.

The first two conditions are easy to show, however I have no idea how to find the inner product $(y, x)$ given the information we have in order to show conditions three and four.

Any help appreciated, I feel like I have missed something quite obvious however I've read through my notes a few times and I can't see anything that would help.

Comment: Hint:  $(\alpha,\beta) =  |\alpha|\, |\beta|\, \cos \theta$

Comment: Also - drawing $R$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is a good idea... $\alpha = (1,0)$, $\beta = (-1,1)$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of the identity you posted, thanks so much; I was wasting so much time trying weird methods with this question. I thought of working out the vectors explicitly as you just did, but I was worried that this might not work for every root system as some share the directions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (for example $C_2$ and $B_2$), does this work regardless due to the set $R$ being different for each root system? If you want to post your answer as a proper answer I will accept it by the way (not sure if this is preferred or not, newish to this site).

Comment: I feel a bit bad posting it as an answer - for the same reason that you felt bad for not thinking of the identity (been there, done that)... But I  have been told in the past that I should post, to take a question off the 'unanswered' queue.  (To answer your side question, if you can draw the root system, it can't hurt... ) To make the answer more respectable, let me add a reference to prof B. Gross  describing the drawing of G2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments - but to take this question off the unanswered queue:

Use $$ (\alpha,\beta) =  |\alpha|\, |\beta|\, \cos \theta.$$

As promised, though not strictly related to the question, see approx. 13 mins into

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxtYFtAA3OY&list=PL5E0D6DC4BCD8309D&index=14

for a description of $G2$. If I recall correctly, the preceding lecture has a nice quick sketch of roots and co-roots, in the context of reductive groups.

Comment: Thanks, video looks helpful for the drawing parts.